# If $X^{0} = \varnothing$ then we can get a finite covering of open sets for $X$?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

let $X \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$  and $X^{0} = \varnothing$ then for all $\delta > 0 $ if $x \in X$ $B(x;\delta)\cap X^c \neq \varnothing$ so by definition of frontier we have $x \in \partial X \Rightarrow X \subset \partial X$ as the frontier is a compact set we can extract a finite covering for $\partial X$ and therefore for $X$. There is a gap in this argumentation?

Comment: "The frontier is a compact set". No. The frontier of $\Bbb Q$ is $\Bbb R$.

Comment: What is mean by $X^0$? Do you mean the interior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not right.  Just consider the straight line $L = \{(x,x) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x \in \mathbb{R}\}$.  This has empty interior in the Euclidean topology, but it's in no way compact.  Also, it's not clear from how you phrased your question whether you're asking if a finite covering exists for a set of this form, or if every open cover has a finite subcover.

Comment: what about $X^{0} = \oslash \Rightarrow X \subset \partial X$??

Comment: @EduardoSilva Of course, since $\partial X = \overline{X} \setminus X^\circ = \overline{X}$ in this case.